# Multiplication application, visual basic. invalid cast exception

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
Dim randomNumberOne As New Random
Dim randomNumberTwo As New Random

Dim ChildGrade As Integer
Dim strChildGrade As Integer
Dim strcorrectCounter As Integer
Dim Correctcounter As Integer = 0
Dim WrongCounter As Integer = 0
Dim totalQuestions As Integer = 0
Dim percent As Integer = 0



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ChildGrade = InputBox("Enter your age ", "age")
    grade()

    FirstNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberOne.Next(0, 12)
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberOne.Next(0, 12)

End Sub

Private Sub grade()
    If ChildGrade <= 4 Then
        Gradelbl.Text = "Preschool"
    ElseIf ChildGrade = 5 Then
        Gradelbl.Text = "Kindergarden"
    ElseIf ChildGrade <= 10 Then
        Gradelbl.Text = "Elementary"
    ElseIf ChildGrade <= 13 Then
        Gradelbl.Text = "Middle School"
    ElseIf ChildGrade <= 18 Then
        Gradelbl.Text = "High School"
    ElseIf ChildGrade > 18 Then
        Gradelbl.Text = "NA"
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub RandomNumberToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RandomNumberToolStripMenuItem.Click
    NumbersGroupBox.Enabled = False
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberOne.Next(0, 12)
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
End Sub

Private Sub SingleTableToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SingleTableToolStripMenuItem.Click
    NumbersGroupBox.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "1"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "2"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "3"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "4"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "5"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "6"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "7"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "8"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "9"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "10"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "11"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = "12"
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckAnswer()
    If TextBox1.Text <> (FirstNumberlbl.Text * SecondNumberlbl.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please try again", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Answer")
        WrongCounter = WrongCounter + 1
        If WrongCounter = 2 Then
            MsgBox("The correct answer is " & FirstNumberlbl.Text * SecondNumberlbl.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Correct answer")
            WrongCounter = 0
            FirstNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberOne.Next(0, 12)
            SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rightAnswer()

    If FirstNumberlbl.Text * SecondNumberlbl.Text = TextBox1.Text Then
        Correctcounter = Correctcounter + 1
        NumberCorrectlbl.Text = Correctcounter
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        FirstNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberOne.Next(0, 12)
        SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    End If
    totalQuestions = totalQuestions + 1

End Sub

Private Sub Enterbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enterbtn.Click
    CheckAnswer()
    rightAnswer()
    TotalCountlbl.Text = totalQuestions
    PercentCorrectlbl.Text = ((Correctcounter * 100) / (totalQuestions * 100)) * 100
End Sub
```

End Class

I'm creating a multiplication application in VB that keeps count of how many questions the user gets right and how many they get wrong. When I run the program, it works fine in counting the amount right and totaling up the percentage, but when I test for when they get it wrong I get this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amKZr.jpg)

if the image isn't visible, the error says, 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

The program points to the problem being in the if statement in the rightAnswer() sub class but i'm not exactly sure what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to do calculations with strings. Strings are text, not numbers.

This is not a full answer but enough to get you to understand the problem and change your code to fix it.

Don't do any calculations on the contents of text boxes and/or labels. Use the correct variables for such tasks. Use the controls for simply retrieving and displaying. This will save you a lot of heart-ache in the long run.

So for example, don't do:

```
If TextBox1.Text <> (FirstNumberlbl.Text * SecondNumberlbl.Text) Then
```

You're checking a number in the TextBox to a calculation based on two labels, they are all text!

So think along the lines of doing calculations on a variable fit for purpose, an integer for example:

Example:

```
Dim FirstNumber As Integer
Dim SecondNumber As Integer
```

Use these for the calculations, then, display the result as text.

If you are expecting a floating point number, a decimal, change the variable type as needed.

In your 'CheckAnswer' subroutine you should starting thinking along the lines of:

```
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then
        'We have something in the TextBox (you can check to allow only numbers to be entered in the TextBox.KeyDown/Press event)
        If Not Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text) = (FirstNumber * SecondNumber) Then
            'Do what you need ...
        End If
    End If
```

There's a couple of other things too that could simplify your code.

You don't need 12 button events all doing the same thing.

In you Form1_Load Event put this:

```
    Dim bTags() As Button = {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8, Button9, Button10, Button11, Button12}
    For t As Integer = 0 To bTags.Count - 1
        bTags(t).Tag = t + 1
    Next
```

Then delete all your 12 Button Click events and replace them with:

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click, Button8.Click, Button7.Click, Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button3.Click, Button2.Click, Button12.Click, Button11.Click, Button10.Click, Button1.Click
    Dim selectedButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    FirstNumberlbl.Text = selectedButton.Tag.ToString
    SecondNumberlbl.Text = randomNumberTwo.Next(0, 12)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Job done...

Also, you grade subroutine would be better of as a `Select Case` function:

In your `Form1_Load` replace:  `grade()` with `Gradelbl.Text = Grade()` and your `grade()` subroutine replaced with:

```
Private Function Grade() As String
    Select Case ChildGrade
        Case < 5 : Return "Preschool"
        Case = 5 : Return "Kindergarden"
        Case < 11 : Return "Elementary"
        Case < 14 : Return "Middle School"
        Case < 19 : Return "High School"
        Case Else : Return "N/A"
    End Select
End Function
```

I hope some of the advice will be of help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is cast the values of the textbox. For example:

```
Convert.toInt32(FirstNumberlbl.Text)
```

or

```
Dim firstNumber as Integer
Integer.TryParse(FirstNumberlbl.Text, firstNumber)
```

Or assign a variable to the textbox and cast the variable instead of the textbox.

Comment: Always prefer Integer.TryParse to validate your string input.

Comment: Yup, by doing this `Int32.TryParse(FirstNumberlbl.Text)`

Comment: [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) has more than one parameter.

Comment: TryParse, not Parse.

Comment: Done. Thank you for spotting out my mistakes